# How to add 'www.' to the beginning of some dataframe values?

Tags: python, string, pandas, iteration

I have the data that contains domain names:

```
 url            var1
www.google.com   xsd
ebay.com         wer
www.amazon.com   xyz
microsoft.com    zyx
....
```

I need to add 'www.' to the domain names that don't have it at the beginning.

I have this code:

```
try: 
for domain in df['url']:
    if domain.startswith('www.'):
        next
    else: 
        domain = 'www.' + domain.astype(str)

except ConnectionResetError:
    print('Handle Exception')
```

The code is generating an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `str` is already a `str`. Why do you need `astype`?

Comment: Also, `next` isn't right... You want `continue`

Comment: `if not domain.startswith('www.'): domain  = "www." + domain`. Done. Well, that won't modify `df['url']`, but only locally...

Comment: also you could try `str(domain)` but like others said its not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a loop when you can `map()` that function over all the rows.

```
def prefixWWW(url):
    return 'www.' + url if not url.startswith('www.') else url

df = df['url'].map(prefixWWW)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [235]: df.loc[~df.url.str.contains(r'^www\.'), 'url'] = \
              'www' + df.loc[~df.url.str.contains(r'^www\.'), 'url']

In [236]: df
Out[236]:
                url var1
0    www.google.com  xsd
1       wwwebay.com  wer
2    www.amazon.com  xyz
3  wwwmicrosoft.com  zyx
```